# After merging, but before committing, how can I force a manual re-merge on a specific file?

Tags: git, merge

During a merge a certain file was auto merged successfully. I now have the results staged but not committed. However I am unhappy with the result in a specific file and want to initiate a 3 way merge manually on said file. Effectively, I want to get the same result as if I'd had a conflict on this file and used `git mergetool` to resolve it. You might say I want to 'force' the conflict.

How can I do this?

I *think* I would use `git merge-file` but it is not clear to me how to tell it which branches/files to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

`git checkout -m <filename>` to remove the file's changes. A `git status` then shows the file is now listed under 'Unmerged paths:'.  Then force it to re-merge using `git mergetool`.

Comment: Also, I think you'll need to run `git mergetool` again once this is complete.